# Shift cipher with word spaces

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to implement a basic method which takes a string and applies a shift to the words alphabet.

The method I've created works fine, but I'm also trying to handle word spaces.

As of now, all spaces are being outputted as '#'.

```
static String encrypt(String message, int shift) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();  
        int length = message.length(); 
        for(int k=0; k < length; k++) {
            char c = (char)(message.charAt(k) + shift);
            if (c == ' ') {
                s.append(' '); 
                continue; 
            }
            if(c > 'z') {
                s.append((char)(message.charAt(k) - (26-shift)));
            } else  {
                s.append((char)(message.charAt(k) + shift)); 
            } 
        }
        return s.toString();
    }
```

I've tried adding a basic if statement:

```
if (c == ' ') {
    s.append(' '); 
}

System.out.println(encrypt("my word", 3));
```

> **Output:** pb#zrug

But doesn't seem to work. Could someone please tell me where I am failing?

Comment: Where did you add that `if`?

Comment: Just before the ` c > 'z'`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the things you need; just put them together in the right order:

```
for(char origChar : message.toCharArray()) {
  if (origChar == ' ') {
    s.append(' '); 
    continue;
  }
  // do other "encryption"
```

In other words: any chars that do **not** require special treatment - you check for them **first**, and then you just "jump" out of the current loop iteration; and continue with the next char in your input.

Please note that there is also no need to use the complicated "counting-for-loop" here; as you can easily iterate over the chars in your input using the "for-each" style of looping.

Comment: can you please explain why char origChar = message.charAt(k);??Thanks

Comment: I've tried checking with an if statement (see updated code)... still getting # in console.

Comment: The **core** point is having that **continue** statement there! And the thing is: dont transform " " into something that you then have to "transform back". Check for " " before doing anything!

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (message.charAt(k) == ' ') {
            s.append(' ');
            continue;
        }
```

Use original char instead of calculated char in if statement.